# Finding the minimum value of a non-linear function over a closed interval in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization, minimization, maximize

Using Matlab, I want to find the minimum value of a non-linear function over a closed interval [0, 1].

```
width_shape_function = @(xV)((1.6)*((1 - (0.501237175635373)*((xV)^(1.23642575949947)))^(1.99283778776976))); 

val = vpa(fminbnd(width_shape_function, 0, 1.0), 20)
```

However, fminbnd finds out the location at which 'width_shape_function' is minimum over an open interval (0, 1).

I request you to help me so that the activity of finding the minimum value of a non-linear function is performed over a closed interval [0, 1].

Comment: Can you not just substitute the location of the minimum back into the original expression to get the value at the location of the minimum?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome It will still not perform the activity of finding the minimum value of a function over a closed interval.

Comment: I see, I missed that part. Will you always be having a 1D interval?  In that case you could also just evaluate at the two boundary points as well.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome yes, I am doing exactly that to account for ends of interval using additional if-else conditions. This is possible because my non-linear function has only one unknown. But I thought there might be a more subtle way of finding out minima over a closed interval in Matlab.

Comment: The difference between the open and closed interval shouldn't matter for continuous functions.

Comment: Also, `vpa` does nothing in your code snippet. It converts the double-precision value into a variable-precision value, but it doesn't make the value more precise. You still are limited by the precision of the double-precision result of `fminbnd`.

Comment: @ Cris Luengo the nature of interval, whether open or closed, will matter while finding minimum value and its location.